# Hide zsh vcs_info on default branch?

Tags: zsh

I want to add Git branch information to my terminal prompt with ZSH but I want to hide that when I am on the default branch, such as "main" or "master". Is there a mechanism to only include branch name in the prompt when is not included in a given ignore list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`, a `precmd` can be set to be executed prior to the display of the prompt; code there can handle just about any condition you want to test. Try adding this to `~/.zshrc`:

```
my_precmd() {
  vcs_info
  local br=$vcs_info_msg_0_
  [[ $br == 'main' || $br == 'master' ]] && br=''
  [[ -n $br ]] && br="(${br}) "
  psvar[1]="$br"
}
autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b'
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd my_precmd
PROMPT='%1v > '
```

More examples and some notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66104574/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69700413/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69368755/).

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! The only two adjustments I made are `br="${br}"` to remove the parentheses and `PROMPT='%1v'` so that there is no ">" symbol and no space on the right.

Comment: Glad it worked! If you're not adding any decorations to the branch name, you can just delete that line;  `br="${br}"` isn't changing the value in the `br` variable.